# Auto generate navigation

Tags: php, html, apache

I have a PHP script which accepts 2 strings and I use mod_rewrite to allow linking to `example.com/test/data.html` instead of `example.com/apage.php?x=example&y=data`. The page then includes a file based on the strings. I want to be able to mark the current page in a navigation list dynamically.

PHP:

```
$x = htmlspecialchars($_GET["x"]);
$y = htmlspecialchars($_GET["y"]);

if (is_file('/www/pages/' . $x . '/' . $y . '.php') {
    include '/www/pages/' . $x . '/' . $y . '.php';
} else {
    echo '<h1>I dont know that page</h1>';
}
```

What I want to do is to use PHP to generate a list of links of 'X' which I have predefined with the actually requested page highlighted. To clarify: I wish to output something like:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="home">Home</li>
    <li>Possible</li> 
    <li class="selected">Values</li>
    <li>of</li>
    <li>X</li>
</ul>
```

This script would be in the main PHP script 'apage.php'.

Any help please?

EDIT:

This is what i've got now:

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach (glob("/www/pages/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename) {
    $actualname = end(explode('/',$filename));

    if ($actualname == $x) {
        echo '<li class="selected">' . $actualname . '</li>';
    } else {
        echo "<li>" . $actualname . "</li>";
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

and using CSS i have the title nicly capitalised. this outputs:

```
<ul>
<li>about</li>
<li>contact</li>
<li>events</li>
<li class="selected">home</li>
<li>info</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `mod_rewrite` can check if a file or directory is requested. Have you considered how the user will load `.css` and `.js` files from their browser, for example?

Comment: i link them from the domain root `/resources/example.file`

Comment: i'm guessing i could add an `elseif` to trap `home` so that i could add it manualy so it appears first in the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Get all possible values using `$possible_values=glob('/www/pages/*/*.php');` then parse file names with `explode('/',$possible_value[N])`.

Comment: this gives me every possible value of x which i can use to generate to bullet list but my main problem was appending `class="selected"` to the current page in the list. i know javascript could be used by this needs to be 100% server side if possible

Comment: When you output a page list in a loop, compare each page file with the current (`'/www/pages/'.$x.'/'.$y.'.php'`) and mark it if match. For further discussion add to your post a loop where you output the list.

Comment: Sorry didn't see your reply but want I want here is a menu of sections/catergorys `$x`. $y is irrelivent to the menu because I don't need a list of all php files within /pages